# Angular 2: 'ngFormModel' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: forms, angular

> My error is

```
 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFormModel' since it isn't a known native property ("
<h3 class = "head">MY PROFILE</h3>

<form  [ERROR ->][ngFormModel]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">

 <div class="row">
"): a@3:7
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("stname</label>
        <input type="text" id="facebook" class="form-control"  ngControl="firstname" [ERROR ->]#firstname="ngForm" >  
   </div>

"): a@9:85
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("/label>
        <input type="text" id="facebook" class="form-control col-xs-3" ngControl="lastname" [ERROR ->]#lastname="ngForm" >  
    </div>
```

> My template,

```
<h3 class="head">MY PROFILE</h3>

<form [ngFormModel]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="formHeading">firstname</label>
            <input type="text" id="facebook" class="form-control" ngControl="firstname" #firstname="ngForm">
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="firstname.touched">
            <div *ngIf="!firstname.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>First name is required</strong>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="formHeading">lastname</label>
            <input type="text" id="facebook" class="form-control col-xs-3" ngControl="lastname" #lastname="ngForm">
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="lastname.touched">
            <div *ngIf="!lastname.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Last name is required</strong>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="formHeading">Profilename</label>
            <input type="text" id="facebook" class="form-control col-xs-3" ngControl="profilename" #profilename="ngForm">
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="formHeading">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" id="facebook" class="form-control col-xs-3" ngControl="phone" #phone="ngForm">
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="phone.touched">
            <div *ngIf="!phone.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Phone number is required</strong>
            </div>
        </div>

        <label class="formHeading">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="fileupload" ngControl="phone">

        <div class="form-row btn">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  " [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

> My Component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {contentHeaders} from '../headers/headers';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/forms';
import {Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import {Control, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './components/profile/profile.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES],
})

export class Profile {

    http: Http;

    form: ControlGroup;

    constructor(fbld: FormBuilder, http: Http, public router: Router) {
        this.http = http;
        this.form = fbld.group({
            firstname: ['', Validators.required],
            lastname: ['', Validators.required],
            profilename: ['', Validators.required],
            image: [''],
            phone: [''],

        });

    }


    onSubmit(form: any) {

        console.log(form);
        let body = JSON.stringify(form);
        var headers = new Headers();
        this.http.post('http://localhost/angular/index.php/profile/addprofile', body, {
                headers: headers
            })
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    if (response.json().error_code == 0) {
                        alert('added successfully');
                        this.router.navigate(['/demo/professional']);
                    } else {
                        alert('fail');

                    }

                });
    }

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest @angular/forms 0.2.0 with rc.4? In your view there is `ngControl`, that is no longer used. I have inserted your template in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uiYZkEWMyXWOkglHZu6N) and it works properly.

Comment: Also all your import for the form in the component are importing from `common`, and not from the new `forms`. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html.

Comment: Robisim, i am not sue about that.....

Comment: Really, I suggest you follow the [Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) to verify that your environment is set up well, and then to follow the guide on new forms that I already posted you.

Comment: @Robisim,thank you very much for u r support,it worked for me by changing the import from '/common/'  to '/forms'

Comment: i got other error,can u check

Comment: Robisim,can u please check my code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just import the following statement in ts,

```
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, Validators, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/forms';
directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
```

Make the following changes in templates,

```
<h3 class = "head">MY PROFILE</h3>

 <form  [ngFormModel]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">     
     <label class="formHeading">firstname</label>
   <input type="text" id="facebook" class="form-control"   [formControl]="form.controls['firstname']">  
   </div>
       <div *ngIf ="firstname.touched">
      <div *ngIf ="!firstname.valid" class = "alert alert-danger">
       <strong>First name is required</strong>
  </div>  
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="formHeading">lastname</label>
<input type="text" id="facebook" class="form-control col-xs-3" [formControl]="form.controls['lastname']">  
   </div>
  <div *ngIf ="lastname.touched" >
     <div *ngIf = "!lastname.valid" class = "alert alert-danger">
         <strong>Last name is required</strong>
     </div>
   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
   <label class="formHeading">Profilename</label>
    <input type="text" id="facebook" class="form-control col-xs-3" [formControl]="form.controls['profilename']" >  
 </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label class="formHeading">Phone</label>
   <input type="text" id="facebook" class="form-control col-xs-3" [formControl]="form.controls['phone']">  
   </div>

  <div *ngIf ="phone.touched" >
     <div *ngIf = "!phone.valid" class = "alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Phone number is required</strong>
     </div>
  </div>

 <div class="form-row btn">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  "    [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
</div>
```

Finally do this in your bootstrapping,

```
import {provideForms, disableDeprecatedForms} from '@angular/forms';
bootstrap(MyDemoApp, [
provideForms(),
disableDeprecatedForms()]);
```

Answer (score 22):

The problem is that you're still importing from `common` and especially using the instructions of the old forms.
Import correctly the components for new forms:

```
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/forms';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
```

And correct the component:

```
@Component({
    ...
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent {

    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(fbld: FormBuilder) {

        this.form = fbld.group({
            ...

        });


    }

    ...

}
```

Then correct the view: `ngFormModel` has been replaced by `formGroup`, and use `formControl` for your fields:

```
<form  [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="form-group">     
            <label class="formHeading">firstname</label>
            <input type="text" id="facebook" class="form-control" [formControl]="form.controls['firstname']" >  
        </div>

        <div *ngIf ="form.controls['firstname'].touched">
            <div *ngIf ="!form.controls['firstname'].valid" class = "alert alert-danger">
            <strong>First name is required</strong>
            </div>  
        </div>

        ... 

        <div class="form-row btn">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>

        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Edit. From Angular 2.0.0-rc.5, is necessary to remove the directives from the component and import the form modules in `AppModule`:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    ...
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

If you use a shared module, do not forget to export them:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    exports: [
        ...
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ]
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: Hi Robibim,finally it worked but with the above modifications i am missing the validation and the error is undefined 'touched'

Comment: You must use: `form.controls['phone'].touched` and `form.controls['phone'].valid`

Comment: now the error got cleared but i am not getting the validations in my form.........

Comment: I had this error using Angular2 RC5.  I had to re-add the `directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]` component property shown above to get it to work, even though I though we weren't supposed to use that anymore.

Comment: Hi @Helzgate. Have you imported `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `AppModule`?

Comment: @robisim74 that was it!  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, It doesn't seem to work for me though I've imported FormModule, ReactiveFormModule

Comment: Great, it only works when directly imported into a Module, can't seem to use a shared Module for those things.

Comment: Hi @MathijsSegers, I've updated my answer with a sample code for rc.5. Greetings

Comment: This is a great solution! Angular's documentation really needs to reflect this. Or if it does already, it needs to be easier to find.

Comment: ...has no exported member 'FORM_DIRECTIVES'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What I did to solve it:

- remove the  tag, and add (click)-function to the button
- checked my backend: there was an error in some special event... fixed it

Now it doesn't fire twice anymore.
So double check this! You never know...