# disableDeprecatedForms() is not working

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am writing an angular 2 application where I have some forms. I am trying to use the new forms but I am not able to. I have my bootstrap file as following:

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { Type } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';
import { ServerGetService } from 'POC/services/server-communication.service';


bootstrap(<Type>AppComponent, [
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  ServerGetService,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms()
])
.catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
```

What is happening is that I still get the warning message telling me that I am using the deprecated forms, moreover I have my forms submitted twice (I believe once by the deprecated forms and the other by the new ones).

When I remove `provideForms()` it still works (with the warning) and it submits the form only once.

I have my template as:

```
<div id="global-settings-popup">
  <form #globalSettingsForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <fieldset class="my-fieldset">
      <legend class="my-fieldset__title">Sample</legend>
      <div class="my-field">
        <label class="my-field__label" for="mode">Mode</label>
        <div class="my-field__content">
          input type="text" class="my-field__input field_input--medium" [(ngModel)]="mysample.prefix" name="prefix" id="prefix"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-popup__footer">
      <button type="submit" class="my-button my-button--primary">OK</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

and in my component I have an `onSubmit()` where I handle the submission logic

what am I missing?

Comment: Can you reproduce in Plunker? https://plnkr.co/edit/9XogrULe6atg4WMOCiqS?p=preview

Comment: I tried to take the relevant parts of the app and put it in the plunker but it is submitting once, btw I am using webpack not systemjs but that shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: How do you submit the form? Can you please add some more code?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347478/ngformmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-property-angular-2 ? Have you tried changing the button to `type="button"`?

Comment: changing the type to button will not submit the form but the problem was in fact in the imports, I was importing the  FORM_DIRECTIVES from common not forms

Answer (score 0):

Simply add name attribute to your fields in form and assign them some value. It is working with me. Notice 'name' attribute in below code.

```
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.email" placeholder="User Name" type="text" autofocus name='usr' required>
```

Comment: I already have the name set on all the fields

Comment: the problem here is that the function disableDeprecatedForms() is just being ignored or sth like that because it isn't causing any difference whether I put it or not

Comment: Please share error summary

Comment: I am not getting any errors I am only getting the warning message that says I am using the old forms

Comment: *It looks like you're using the old forms module. This will be opt-in in e next RC, and  will eventually be removed in favor of the new forms module. For more information, see: https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/1RIezQqE4aEhBRmArIAS1mRIZtWFf6JxN_7B4meyWK0Y/pub

Comment: update your angular with RC4